# Detecting when my application is sent to the Background because of a Call

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I need to detect when my BlackBerry application is sent to the background and also when it's brought to the foreground again. I need to pause the application when a phone call comes in and resume appropriately.

I assume this must be trivial to achieve but I can't find any reference to how this is done. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Application.activate()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#activate()) and [Application.deactivate()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#deactivate()) methods - just override those methods in your app to define some custom behavior when these events occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know that the specific reason your app was sent to the background is because of an incoming phone call you can implement the [PhoneListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html) interface and register via `Phone.addPhoneListener(listener)`.